# Unable to locate data source for scraping

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape the price for each tire size for this website

https://www.lazada.com.my/products/free-installtion-michelin-pilot-sport-5-ps5-pilot-sport-4-ps4-16-17-18-19-20-21-inch-tyre-tayar-tire-free-instalation-i2362229944-s10189996251.html?

I know they are loading a javascript to fetch data and has implemented scrapy splash. However the only thing I could find in the html script was the RM 470 price. But I tested this without internet and whenever I click a different size for example 205/45R17 the price changes to reflect the new size. So I know they have loaded this out but could not find in the html.

Could you guys help me out?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like when you click on the buttons to change the tire type, the HTML page gets swapped with a new one. You will need to scrape each of the pages separately.